# How to communicate C# desktop application with JS (web application)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, communication

My problem is that I have a C# exe file which detects local machine configuration and this result must be sent back to web application.

This exe file is placed o web page and must be started manually be user. But my web application must receive the detection results back to JS app (web browser ) from exe file.

I have solution where exe file starts Owin web server (http), and JS app calls it and received results . it works, but it works in mixed mode because web application works as https but owin works as http. **How to run Owin in https?** Is it secure ( malicious user can de-compile exe file and take over this SSL certificate)?

How to do it this communication which will be mostly automatic and secure?

Comment: I don't think HTTPS will provide any guarantee of the client's trustworthiness. I think the only thing HTTPS can provide is that communications between the client and the server are not intercepted and/or interfered with. Also, you are quite correct -- it is trivial for a malicious user to decompile a .NET exe, and unless you've obfuscated your code, said user will be able to find the security information.

Comment: How about having the EXE file talk to your web server instead? Then the Javascript code can ask the web server for the data.

Comment: Yeah I found it too @Tanner, but I have to pass any session taken/parameter to exe file, to use it when data are sent to server ... How to pass this parameter to exe file.